# writing into file based on condition

Tags: python

I want to deidentify some text in a file and write into another file. Here's what I've done.

```
    Replace1 = re.sub(pattern1, "**name**", read_file)
    Replace2 = re.sub(pattern2, "**name**", read_file)
    with open("filename", "w")as f:
        f.write(Replace1)
        f.write(Replace2)
    f.close()
```

but the output file write it two time. fist it writes the first Replace1 and keeps the Replace to identify and the do the same for the next one. I want to do it in one time.

Comment: I cannot understand your question, please rephrase it with some examples.

Comment: let's say I have a file like this:
Fake name information is a: hju55h3@gmail.com
Fake name Mary T information is: lwt5864hrS@yahoo.com
Ms. Fake name information is: S568sJ@yahoo.com
I wrote the pattern to deidentified names and email.
I want to write it into another file. 
My question is about writing into a file. How can I write both of my pattern in one time?

Comment: I want something like this:

           f.write(Replace1, Replace2)
which go through the line If pattren1 exist write if pattern2 write.

Comment: Small note, when you leave the indentation after `with`, the file `f` closes itself - you shouldn't need `f.close()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `Replace1` as the input string in `Replace2`. Then just write `Replace2` into a file.

```
Replace1 = re.sub(pattern1, "**name**", read_file)
Replace2 = re.sub(pattern2, "**name**", Replace1)

with open("filename", "w")as f:
    f.write(Replace2)
f.close()
```